# Oracle SQL SELECT unexpected behaviour

Tags: sql, oracle

In legacy code I have found some strange SQL SELECT query which caused bug in our application. My Oracle version is **11.2.0.1.0**. Below (simplified) code:

**DDL:**

```
DROP TABLE A;
DROP TABLE B;
DROP TABLE C;

CREATE TABLE "A"
  (
    "ID_B"              NUMBER NOT NULL
  );

CREATE INDEX "A_INDEX" ON "A"("ID_B");

CREATE TABLE "B"
  (
    "ID"                NUMBER NOT NULL,
    "NAME"              VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
    "SURNAME"           VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
    CONSTRAINT "PK_B" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  );

CREATE TABLE "C"
  (
    "ID"                NUMBER NOT NULL
  );


INSERT INTO A(ID_B) VALUES (10);
INSERT INTO B(ID, SURNAME, NAME) VALUES(10, 'LUCKY', 'LUKE');
COMMIT;
```

**SELECT**:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      B.ID,
      B.SURNAME,
      B.NAME
    FROM A
      LEFT JOIN B ON B.ID = A.ID_B
      LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM C WHERE ID = 10) C ON  1 = 1
    WHERE A.ID_B = 10
  );
```

**PROBLEM:**
Could You help me understand why select *count(*)* returns 0 as result by sub-query returns 1 result row? 
When I drop 'A_INDEX' both select works fine *(count(*)* returns 1).

Comment: Please post `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT...` for both cases

Comment: That is .... weird, and it works properly with the index also if you change the outer join to use c,id = a.id_b instead of the 1=1 which is an odd construct to use anyway.

Comment: @lad2025 my execution plan is exactly the same as posted below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the index the query with count(*) hat this execution plan 
**in Linux: Version 11.2.0.3.0**

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |      |     1 |    15 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE       |      |     1 |    15 |            |          |
|   2 |   MERGE JOIN OUTER    |      |     1 |    15 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL  | A    |     1 |    13 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |    BUFFER SORT        |      |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |     VIEW              |      |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL| C    |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - filter("A"."ID_B"=10)
   6 - filter("ID"=10)
```

Note that Oracle doesn't access table B and performs outer join on A and C,
which leads to result 1 - **correct**

*With the index on A* - Oracle open  `CARTESIAN JOIN` which leads to result 1 * 0 = 0 (this join is not `OUTER`)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |         |     1 |    15 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE       |         |     1 |    15 |            |          |
|   2 |   MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN|         |     1 |    15 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    VIEW               |         |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL | C       |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |    BUFFER SORT        |         |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN  | A_INDEX |     1 |    13 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   4 - filter("ID"=10)
   6 - access("A"."ID_B"=10)
```

Sorry for the bad news, IMO this is a wrong optimization in Oracle, the only chance is to open SR (or to workaround it with drop index or reformulate the query).

For completness, the plan for the query with the hint  `/*+ NO_QUERY_TRANSFORMATION */`
The table `B` is now accessed and both joins are outer, so it works fine.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                      | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |         |     1 |    80 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  MERGE JOIN OUTER              |         |     1 |    80 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   MERGE JOIN OUTER             |         |     1 |    80 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN            | A_INDEX |     1 |    13 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |    BUFFER SORT                 |         |     1 |    67 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| B       |     1 |    67 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | PK_B    |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |   BUFFER SORT                  |         |     1 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   8 |    VIEW                        |         |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  9 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL          | C       |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - access("A"."ID_B"=10)
   6 - access("B"."ID"(+)=10)
   9 - filter("ID"=10)
```

Comment: Tried adding the hint /*+ NO_QUERY_TRANSFORMATION */, in the external query, it seems to work well; (tested on Oracle 11.2.0.3.0)

Comment: @Aleksej correct, I added the  hinted plan to see why.

Answer (score 2):

In 11.2.0.4 I get 1 for the count with or without the index. The plan with the index:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |         |     1 |    13 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE       |         |     1 |    13 |            |          |
|   2 |   MERGE JOIN OUTER    |         |     1 |    13 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN   | A_INDEX |     1 |    13 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |    BUFFER SORT        |         |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |     VIEW              |         |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL| C       |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                              
---------------------------------------------------                              

   3 - access("A"."ID_B"=10)                                                     
   6 - filter("ID"=10)
```

And without:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
| Id  | Operation             | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |   
------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |      |     1 |    13 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |   
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE       |      |     1 |    13 |            |          |   
|   2 |   MERGE JOIN OUTER    |      |     1 |    13 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |   
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL  | A    |     1 |    13 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |   
|   4 |    BUFFER SORT        |      |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |   
|   5 |     VIEW              |      |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |   
|*  6 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL| C    |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |   
------------------------------------------------------------------------------   

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                              
---------------------------------------------------                              

   3 - filter("A"."ID_B"=10)                                                     
   6 - filter("ID"=10)
```

Since that isn't the behaviour see in 11.2.0.3, its presumably fixed in the 11.2.0.4 patchset (or one of the CPUs; this environment includes the October 2015 CPU, with no additional patches). Partly based on our comment that `/*+ NO_QUERY_TRANSFORMATION */` works around it, this looks similar to bug 12638091, but it doesn't look like that should affect 11.2.0.3 - only way to be sure is to raise a service request though.

Comment: I will try to check it on 11.2.0.4 - thanks for a hint

Comment: @Mydory - more specifically this was on 11.2.0.4.7 (i.e. including the October 2015 critical patch update), on Linux. I didn't spot anything obviously relevant in the published information about the patchset or CPU.